# Bootstrap datepicker - Please be specific because the other examples are too generic

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datapicker

I am following the guide at https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker
to implement a simple startDate/endDate datapickers layout.

I copypasted the code from the examples in fiddle but it won't work.

Do I need to import the CSS to make it work??
If it is not the CSS the problem, than what is that is preventing the data-pickers from showing up?

This is a part of the code:
    $('#date-start').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){

```
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > endDate.valueOf()){
        $('#alert').show().find('strong').text('The start date must be before the end date.');
    } else {
        $('#alert').hide();
        startDate = new Date(ev.date);
        $('#date-start-display').text($('#date-start').data('date'));
    }
    $('#date-start').datepicker('hide');
});
```

this is the fiddle example

```
http://jsfiddle.net/wadvc/
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker' -- this means you don't have TBS most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include Bootstrap and the 'datepicker' plugin.. your fiddle doesn't seem to have these.

Here is a [**working demo on Bootply**](http://bootply.com/60791) which includes the Bootstrap for you.

Comment: I imported both the twitter bootstrap and the datapicker plugin:

if I use these lines of code:

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
it works,

if I use the code from the examples it won't.

Comment: Solved! I was setting the ID in the div, after setting it into the input tag it works.